# Emulated clicks aren't working inside other programs

Tags: java, mouseclick-event

I would like to create a bot to farm in an online game so the code I am using to emulate a click is this:

```
    Robot bot = new Robot();
    bot.mouseMove(x, y);    
    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK);
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK);
```

This code works really fine and everything is good anywhere on the screen but when it comes to the game it doesn't respond it's like I am not clicking at all, It's not working I am using windows 10 and some people said that some programs without admin rights can't emulate a click on programs that can ( The game requires admin right to open ) So I opened my java program with admin rights enabled and nothing changed I would like help on the matter thank you for your time

Comment: Most games forbid botting.

Comment: Yeah but I want to try I am not with botting but I wanna learn more about this